# differentiation with respect to a quaternion

Tags: derivatives, quaternions

My question is as follows: if I have a unit quaternion(used to represent the rotation) $q=[q_{0}\,\textbf{q}]$ and a pure quaternion $v=[0\,\textbf{v}]$,where $\textbf{v}$ is a 3x1 vector.* is the quaternion multiplication.

1. what is $\frac{\partial (q*v*q^{-1})}{\partial v}$? could you show me which one of following options is right?

> I have searched some materials about quaternion derivatives, and one of them([https://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/quaternion.pdf](https://web.cs.iastate.edu/%7Ecs577/handouts/quaternion.pdf)) show an result like:$\frac{\partial (q*v*q^{-1})}{\partial v}=(q_{0}^2-||\textbf{q}||^2)I_{3}+2\textbf{q}\textbf{q}^T-2q_{0}\textbf{q}\times$

> Another potential answer is:$\frac{\partial (q*v*q^{-1})}{\partial v}=q*e_{i}*q^{-1}$, where $e_{i}$ are basis of inertial frame.

2. what is $\frac{\partial (q*v*q^{-1})}{\partial q}$?
3. what is $\frac{\partial (q*p^{-1})}{\partial q}$? p is also a unit quaternion.

Comment: Have you consulted [MSE question 2570065](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2570065) "Derivative of a rotated vector with respect to the quaternion"?

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll change your notation slightly, denoting multiplication as$$[a,\,u][b,\,v]=[ab-u\cdot v,\,av+bu+u\times v]$$so$$\begin{align}qvq^{-1}&=\frac{[q_0,\,q][0,\,v][q_0,\,-q]}{q_0^2+q^2}\\&=\frac{[-q\cdot v,\,q_0v-q\times v][q_0,\,-q]}{q_0^2+q^2}\\&=\frac{[0,\,2(q\cdot v)q+(q_0^2-q^2)v+2q_0v\times q]}{q_0^2+q^2},\end{align}$$with $q^2=q\cdot q$ in terms of the $3$-vector $q$. Differentiation with respect to $v_a,\,a\in\{1,\,2,\,3\}$ gives a pure quaternion whose $b$th imaginary entry, $b\in\{1,\,2,\,3\}$, is$$\frac{2q_aq_b+(q_0^2-q^2+2q_0\times q)\delta_{ab}}{q_0^2+q^2}.$$You can treat parts 2, 3 similarly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what's your meaning of $q_{a}q_{b}$ of your formula above. Does that means actually the derivatives of my question1 is a 3x3 matrix because $a\in {1,2,3}$ and $b\in {1,2,3}$? Also,what is $\delta_{ab}$?

Comment: @DarkKnight The [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).